# Start AltBeacon in another process

Tags: android, xamarin, process, altbeacon

The service on Xamarin.Android is started in a separate process. The service implements the AltBeacon v2.12 library.
The DidRangeBeaconsInRegion callback method does not work in the RangeNotifier object.
After the start of the ranging of the bicons (the method StartRangingBeaconsInRegion (region)) the beacons are not determined.

Code:

1. Service definition:

   `[Service(Name = SERVICE_NAME, Process = ":myProcess", Enabled = true, Exported = false, IsolatedProcess = false)]`
2. Configuring BeaconManager (Defined in the Service)

   ```
   beaconManager = BeaconManager.
      GetInstanceForApplication(DroidApplication.Current);
   rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier();
   beaconManager.ForegroundBetweenScanPeriod = 1000;
   beaconManager.ForegroundScanPeriod = 1000; 
   beaconManager.BackgroundMode = false; 
   var beaconParser = new BeaconParser();
   beaconParser.SetBeaconLayout("...");
   beaconManager.BeaconParsers.Add(beaconParser);
   beaconManager.AddRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
   beaconManager.ApplySettings();
   ```

3.Service code:

```
 public class BeaconService:Service,IBeaconConsumer
    ...
    {
    private async void DoWork()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                   lg.Error("DOWORK");
                   beaconManager.Bind(this);
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                   beaconManager.Unbind(this);    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }


     public bool BindService(Intent p0, IServiceConnection p1, int p2)
    {

       return this.BindService(p0, p1,Bind.AutoCreate);
    }


    public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()
    {


        string[] guids = { "....","...." };

        foreach (var region in beaconManager.RangedRegions.ToList())
            beaconManager.StopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);

        for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++)
        {
            var uuid = Identifier.Parse(guids[i]);
            var region = new Region("R" + i, uuid, null, null);
            beaconManager.StartRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        }
    }



    private class RangeNotifier
    {       
    //This method doesn't invoke
        public void DidRangeBeaconsInRegion(ICollection<Beacon> beacons, Region region)
        {
            Logger lg = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            lg.Debug(String.Format("COUNT -{0}",beacons.Count));

        }   
    }
}
```

I did not call BeaconManager.IsMainProcess because the definition and configuration of BeaconManager occurs in the service itself, which is started in another process.

1. By logs it is visible that scanning works in the main process. How can this be if I start the service in a separate process? The configuration of the BaconManager object and the BaconManager startup takes place directly in the Service. Bind also occurs in the service.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm1oj.jpg)
2. Is it acceptable in this case to define the service settings in the attributes of the class as in my example, or do I strictly need to register them in the application manifest?
3. Do I need to define the BeaconIntentProcessor?
4. I suspect that I do not correctly define - beaconManager = BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication (DroidApplication.Current);
5. How to start the scan correctly? From the main application process (for example, from an activation or from a custom DroidApplication class) or is it possible from the service?

My manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="myPackageApp" android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="0.12.3" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<permission android:name="myApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<application android:label="@string/gen_application_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:largeHeap="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="..." />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Running the library's scanning service in a different process is tricky enough when you are doing all the work in Java in Android Studio and have only a single main application process.  Throw Xamarin into the mix, then add an existing separate process, and you really have your work cut out for you!  That said, here are some tips that might help:

- I am not an expert about what happens on Android when you use service A to start service B when service A is in a separate process.    Perhaps Android does start service B in the main process unless you configure it otherwise.
- Try disabling the beacon scanning service start from your separate process.  If you find that the scanning service is still running in the main process, then something in that process must be calling bind() or using RegionBootstrap (which calls bind() internally) to get it to start up.  If you are using a third party library it may be inside that library.
- Be aware that the library itself has its own manifest, so its entries may get merged with your manifest.  Check to see if there is a generated manifest that combines more elements.
- I am not familiar with defining service parameters in the manner described in your first question, so I can't say if it would cause trouble.
- I see no reason to define a BeaconIntentProcessor.  The library should do that for you.
- It should be possible to start scanning from a service, activity or application class.  Set a breakpoint or log line inside your `OnBeaconServiceConnect()` definition and make sure it is getting called.  If so, you started the service correctly, and you have instantiated your `BeaconManager` properly.

**EDIT:** Based on the discussion in the comments, it appears that a key problem is the place where `beaconManager.AddRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);` is called.  This must be called in the process where callbacks are expected to be received.  Although `BeaconManager` is a singleton, in Android (and all Linux) multi process applications there is one copy of a singleton for each process. 
  So if you add your notifiers on the background process instance of `BeaconManager` that is where the callbacks will be received.  If you want the callbacks to be received on the main UI process, you must set the notifiers from the instance of `BeaconManager` that exists in that process.

Comment: Thank you, David! The point is that when I did the Xamarin wrapper for the AltBeacon v2.12 library and launched it in the main process - everything works ok, finds the beacons.
  When I started the service in a separate process, the OnServiceConnect method also works and starts the ranging.
  The only problem is that DidRangeBeaconsInRegion method does not work in RangeNotifier.

Comment: Apologies, but you'll want to use v2.11 as v2.12 changes the way intents are delivered for ranging (at least on Android 8 devices).  If you still don't see the ranging callbacks, then the issue may be that the global intents are not getting delivered from the scanning process to the foreground process, and this might be caused by the package name in the processes not being the same.  The line of code that creates the intent to be delivered to the foreground looks like this: `intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), "org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor"));`

Comment: Thanks you! But so far I have not been able to achieve the desired result.
I learned your library. But I'm not an expert in Java and Android.
But I was able to debug the implementation.
I found out that the BeaconIntentProcessor class is called successfully.
It calls the "convertIntentsToCallbacks" method of the IntentHandler class.
It contains the data of the beacons - rangingData! = Null
But the problem itself is in the RangeNotifiers
Set <RangeNotifier> notifiers = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication (context) .getRangingNotifiers ();
Notifiers  is empty.

Comment: As far as I understand, the problem is in the beaconManager instance, which I get from the BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication (context) method.It turns out that when you create the BeaconManager object, it is created in one process (in the main process)and the addition of RangeNotifiers occurs in a different process.
I can not understand how this can be if I create a beaconManager in another process (not the main one).

Comment: In the main process, I have activity. In another process, I create my own service, which deals with the main job.
In this service I create a BeaconManager and add a RangeNotifier to it and then start the ranging.
I can not understand why BeaconManager runs in the main process and not in the additional one where the service is running?
Can I get an instance in BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication (context) that was started and configured in an additional process?

Comment: This empty notifiers may be a key part of the problem.  See my edit to the answer.

Comment: OK. I understood what you wrote about in edit. I figured out the notifications. The whole problem was the getInstanceForApplication method
when called in beaconIntentProcessor (this is what you wrote earlier). It turns out that beaconIntentProcessor received the context of the main process.
In the main process there is no created beaconManager object and therefore it created a new clean object without rangeNotifiers.
In the library manifest, I added the android attribute: process = ": myServiceProcess" in beaconService and beaconIntentProcessor.
After that, the callback calls were made.

Comment: But the problem did not dare completely.
Although the call is triggered but the number of visible bicons is 0.
If you turn off and turn on the bluetooth on the device, it starts to catch them.
But unfortunately with the start of the application, he does not see them. It is necessary to restart the bluetooth all the time.
You do not know what might be the problem?

Comment: If you restart the bluetooth, then the bicons are determined for 5 minutes and then 0 again.

Comment: after 5 minutes the cycledLeScannerForLollipop starts to give a log error - "Scan failed, app cannot be registered"

Comment: and log error  - onClientRegistered() - status=133.

Comment: the status should be 0 as I understand it

Comment: I think this is a completely different problem.  I am happy to discuss (I think I have a solution for you), but can you please open a new question about the 133 error and link to it from here?

Comment: Thank you David, I posted new question in post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823868/error-scan-failed-app-cannot-be-registered-in-scanning-beacons-in-altbeacon-l